# PHP - inserting record to mysql from form

Tags: php, mysql

This is the table that is not writing all data to, but which should have the data inserted:

```
members_posts
`screenname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`images_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`item` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
`noi` varchar(124) DEFAULT NULL,
`notes` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`posted` timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `screenname_idx` (`screenname`),
CONSTRAINT `screenname_posts` FOREIGN KEY (`screenname`) REFERENCES `members`   (`screenname`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

When I attempt to open my postitem.php page, it loads the page, but already inserts the ID, NOTES, and POSTED fields - before entering any data into the form.

Here is the postitem.php form:

```
<?php 

// Connection data to the database 
require("/config/common.php");

// Check to see whether the screen name is already in use.
$query = "SELECT 1 FROM members WHERE screenname = :screenname"; 


$query_params = array( 
':screenname' => $_POST['screenname']); 

try 
{ 
// These two statements run the query against your database table. 
$stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
$result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 
die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 

$row = $stmt->fetch(); 

if($row) 
{ 
die("This screen name is already in use"); 
} 

$query = "INSERT INTO members_posts (screenname, item, noi, notes) 
VALUES (:screenname, :item, :noi, :notes)"; 

$query_params = array( 
':screenname' => $_POST['screenname'], ':item' => $_POST[$item], ':noi' =>     $_POST[$noi], ':notes' => $_POST['notes']); 

try 
{ 
$stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
$result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 
die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 

// Redirects the member back to the member's account page after posting an item. 
//header("Location: myacct.php"); 


//die("Redirecting to myacct.php"); 


?> 
<br />
<br />
<table align="center"> 
<th><h1>Post Item</h1></th>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="postitem.php" method="post">
<tr><td>Screen Name:</td><td><b><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']   ['screenname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></b></td></tr> 
<tr><td>Item:</td><td><select name="item">
<option VALUE='opt1'>Option 1</option>
<option VALUE='opt2'>Option 2</option>
<option VALUE='opt3'>Option 3/Computer</option>
</select></td></tr>
<tr><td>Name of item:</td><td><input type="text" name="noi" value="" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Notes:</td><td><input type="text" name="notes" value="" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" src="/images/postit.png" value="Upload It" /></td></tr>
</form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance for any help anyone could offer me!

PS: I did make the redirection to the myacct.php only a remark for testing, to keep the postitem page open for troubleshooting reasons.

Comment: You're not actually checking to see if any data has been posted. You're just running all of your code (including the queries) regardless.

Comment: Imaibou below added the if(isset($_POST['submit_form'})) to my code, but that did not help.  Do you know how I can check, in the code, to verify data entered is written to the table?  Thanks for your reply, by the way.

Comment: Did you also add that attribute `name="submit_form"` to your submit button? If not, you need to.  You should update the code in your question with the current code that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You should always check if the user submitted the form first befor making database queries like this:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit_form']))
{
    // Connection data to the database 
    require("/config/common.php");

    // Check to see whether the screen name is already in use.
    $query = "SELECT 1 FROM members WHERE screenname = :screenname"; 


    $query_params = array( 
    ':screenname' => $_POST['screenname']); 

    try 
    { 
    // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

    if($row) 
    { 
    die("This screen name is already in use"); 
    } 

    $query = "INSERT INTO members_posts (screenname, item, noi, notes) 
    VALUES (:screenname, :item, :noi, :notes)"; 

    $query_params = array( 
    ':screenname' => $_POST['screenname'], ':item' => $_POST['item'], ':noi' =>     $_POST['noi'], ':notes' => $_POST['notes']); 

    try 
    { 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    // Redirects the member back to the member's account page after posting an item. 
    //header("Location: myacct.php"); 


    //die("Redirecting to myacct.php"); 

}
?> 
<br />
<br />
<table align="center"> 
<th><h1>Post Item</h1></th>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="postitem.php" method="post">
<tr><td>Screen Name:</td><td><b><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']   ['screenname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></b></td></tr> 
<tr><td>Item:</td><td><select name="item">
<option VALUE='opt1'>Option 1</option>
<option VALUE='opt2'>Option 2</option>
<option VALUE='opt3'>Option 3/Computer</option>
</select></td></tr>
<tr><td>Name of item:</td><td><input type="text" name="noi" value="" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Notes:</td><td><input type="text" name="notes" value="" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" src="/images/postit.png" value="Upload It" name="submit_form" /></td></tr>
</form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that added a name attribute to the submit input tag

Comment: Thank you for your respons, imaibou.  After adding "if(isset($_POST['submit_form']))
{" like you suggested, no data is being written to my table.

Comment: add the line   echo 'inside if';   just after   if(isset($_POST['submit_form'])) {      to see if it enters the if after form validation. Did you make sure to add the name attribute to the subbmit field ? like this:   <input type="submit" src="/images/postit.png" value="Upload It" name="submit_form" />

Answer (score 0):

Put the whole insert-script within a

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // SQL-commands here
}
```

Besides that you may also want to check if the user enters a valid (non-empty) screenname etc.

Answer (score 0):

First give a name to your submit button(in this example 'submit') and then check if it has been pushed looking at the _POST array.

Here the code:

```
    <?php 

    // Connection data to the database 
    require("/config/common.php");
if($_POST['submit']){
    // Check to see whether the screen name is already in use.
    $query = "SELECT 1 FROM members WHERE screenname = :screenname"; 


    $query_params = array( 
    ':screenname' => $_POST['screenname']); 

    try 
    { 
    // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

    if($row) 
    { 
    die("This screen name is already in use"); 
    } 

    $query = "INSERT INTO members_posts (screenname, item, noi, notes) 
    VALUES (:screenname, :item, :noi, :notes)"; 

    $query_params = array( 
    ':screenname' => $_POST['screenname'], ':item' => $_POST[$item], ':noi' =>     $_POST[$noi], ':notes' => $_POST['notes']); 

    try 
    { 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    // Redirects the member back to the member's account page after posting an item. 
    //header("Location: myacct.php"); 


    //die("Redirecting to myacct.php"); 
 }

    ?> 
<br />
<br />
<table align="center"> 
<th><h1>Post Item</h1></th>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="postitem.php" method="post">
<tr><td>Screen Name:</td><td><b><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']   ['screenname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></b></td></tr> 
<tr><td>Item:</td><td><select name="item">
<option VALUE='opt1'>Option 1</option>
<option VALUE='opt2'>Option 2</option>
<option VALUE='opt3'>Option 3/Computer</option>
</select></td></tr>
<tr><td>Name of item:</td><td><input type="text" name="noi" value="" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Notes:</td><td><input type="text" name="notes" value="" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" name='submit' src="/images/postit.png" value="Upload It" /></td></tr>
</form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```